# Simple way to run methods asynchronously in .NET 4?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asynchronous

This is a simple .NET 4 application. Here's the code I want to run:

```
string username = "userfoo";
string password = "passwordfoo";

for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{    
    uint matchId;
    if (!uint.TryParse(i.ToString(), out matchId))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Match ID!");
        return;
    }

    Client client = new Client (username, password, matchId);

    // connect
    client.Connect();

    client.Wait();

    if (client.Match != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting match: #{0}", client.Match.match_id);
        Helpers.MatchHelper.AddMatchToDatabase(client.Match);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get match: #{0}", 1);
    }
```

}

Instead doing this one by one (it would take forever - 415 days nonstop according to my calculations), what's the easiest way to invoke each iteration of this for loop asynchronously?

Most questions and articles are very old (circa 2001!) surely there must be a more modern approach?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301332.aspx

Comment: have you considered using Tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx. Basically, you just use `Parallel.For(0, n, x => doSomething)`. That takes care of parallelization. This is a functionality of PLINQ that is extremely easy to use an in my experience works quite well.

Your sample would look like this:

```
string username = "userfoo";
string password = "passwordfoo";

Parallel.For(0, 2000, i =>
{    
    uint matchId;
    if (!uint.TryParse(i.ToString(), out matchId))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Match ID!");
        return;
    }

    Client client = new Client (username, password, matchId);

    // connect
    client.Connect();

    client.Wait();

    if (client.Match != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting match: #{0}", client.Match.match_id);
        Helpers.MatchHelper.AddMatchToDatabase(client.Match);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get match: #{0}", 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up with something similar in my initial test. I'm curious: since this uses the internet to fetch data, opening up 2000 connections at once to download information makes nothing download at all. Is there a way to *limit* the amount of tasks being launched at a time? Like say, 40 executions at any given time?

Comment: To my understanding that is not how it works. It opens an "appropriate" amount of threads based on the capability of your machine. But I am not aware of any way that would let you explicitly define the parallelism level.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: You could look into the Reactive Extensions library. Basically it acts as an asynchronous collection and it is really powerful. But it requires some investment to understand it properly (I'm still in the 'struggling phase' :D)

Comment: You can limit the amount of tasks using the ParalelOptions object. I'll write an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the info, that thread count limitation is good to know about.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71285/Introducing-NET-4-0-Parallel-Programming

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [task parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you want to run these in a separate thread. Here's one way to do this:
You need to move the code from the loop into a void function:

```
void MyThreadInsteadOfLoop(object parameter)
{
int i  = (int)parameter;
uint matchId;
if (!uint.TryParse(i.ToString(), out matchId))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Match ID!");
    return;
}

Client client = new Client (username, password, matchId);

// connect
client.Connect();

client.Wait();

if (client.Match != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inserting match: #{0}", client.Match.match_id);
    Helpers.MatchHelper.AddMatchToDatabase(client.Match);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get match: #{0}", 1);
}
}
```

In your main thread, you need to prepare threads to run, start them, and wait them to finish, if you want to. Here's the code:

```
//Create threads
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
{
    threads.Add(new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyThreadInsteadOfLoop)));
}
//Start threads
int x = 0;
foreach(var t in threads)
{
    t.Start(x);
    x++;
}
//wait for the threads to finish
foreach(var t in threads)
{
    t.Join();
}
```

Be aware, that you have to make the MatchHelper class, and other classes that exchange data with your threads thread safe, and that tends to add lots of overhead to your program. Also, you can possibly run into trouble with the network connections.
Only [NumberOfCpuCores]*2 threads will actively work (*2 because of hyper-threading) at a time, but since you have to wait for the client (I really hope that's not a while(true) cycle cloaked) that might get concealed at least partly.